# VueJs Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "@vue/app" relative to directory

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm using vue-tour in my app, the problem is that when i imported the library my app doesn't work anymore, this the error when i try the command `npm run dev`:

```
 error  in ./~/vue-tour/dist/vue-tour.umd.js

Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "@vue/app" relative to directory "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\avanttia\\node_modules\\vue-tour"
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:293:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
    at new File (C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:46:20)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\xampp\htdocs\avanttia\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:163:20)

 @ ./resources/assets/js/wizard/main.js 49:15-34
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/wizard/main.js
```

Importing the library like this:

```
import '@/bootstrap'

import VueDragDrop from 'vue-drag-drop'
import VueTour from 'vue-tour'

import Wizard from '@/wizard/containers/Wizard.vue'

require('/node_modules/vue-tour/dist/vue-tour.css')

const Vue = window.Vue

Vue.use(VueTour)
Vue.use(VueDragDrop)

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#wizard-app',
  render: h => h(Wizard)
})

export default vm
```

**Edit:**
This is mi .babelrc config file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [ "env", {
      "targets": {
        "uglify": true,
        "node": "current"
      },
      "modules": false,
      "loose": true,
      "useBuiltIns": true,
      "debug": true,
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["component", [{
      "libraryName": "element-ui",
      "styleLibraryName": "theme-chalk"
    }]],
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "@": "./resources/assets/js"
      }
    }],
    ["transform-es2015-template-literals", {
      "loose": true,
      "spec": true
    }]

  ],

}
```

and the .babelrc config file from the vue-tour library:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@vue/app"
  ]
}
```

Why vue can't find @vue/app?, looks like there is a conflict in the alias property, but i have no idea how to change without breaking the project config.

**update:**
if in the node_modules/vue-tour library i change the .babalrc file to this:

```
"presets": [
        "es2015"
      ]
```

it works as expected, but this is undesired as i have to change everywhere i have to deploy this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days struggling with this issue, i finally found a solution for this:

In the webpack.mix.js the es2015 transpilation was done like this:

```
  {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(some-library)\/).*/,
        include: [/node_modules\/vue-tour/], // <---Added this line!
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had different configurations, got the same error.
I changed `presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2']` from `presets: ['@vue/app']` in my babel.config.js file and added the correct paths to jest.config.json file in `collectCoverageFrom` array.
Now I'm able to see the results in the table format on the terminal.